# Custom Ribbon Sharepoint 2013 Custom Action with javascript

Tags: javascript, error, xml

I would create a custom ribbon in Sharepoint 2013. I created my APP-Sharepoint Hosted APP and I have added my Custom Ribbon . This Custom Ribbon, with a click under it, must open a dialog box or simply an alert.

I have used this code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <CustomAction
      Id="ShowHelloWorldButton"
      RegistrationType="ContentType"
      RegistrationId="0x01"
      Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"
      Rights="EditListItems">
        <CommandUIExtension>
          <CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIDefinition
             Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children">
              <Button
               Id="Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls.ShowHelloWorldButton"
               Alt="Show HelloWorld Alert"
               Sequence="1"
               Image32by32="_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png"
               Image16by16="_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png" 
               Command="ShowHelloWorldCommand"
               LabelText="Hello World"
               TemplateAlias="o1"
               CommandType="General"/>
            </CommandUIDefinition>
          </CommandUIDefinitions>
          <CommandUIHandlers>
            <CommandUIHandler
             Command="ShowHelloWorldCommand"
             CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello World');" />
          </CommandUIHandlers>
        </CommandUIExtension>
      </CustomAction>
    </Elements>
```

But I obtain this error:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Install app for SharePoint': There
>   were errors when validating the App Package.

Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get the error if you try to deploy without the custom action as well?

Comment: Without custom action the custom ribbon there isn't :(

Comment: Could it be permission? Have you tried, just for the sake of testing, to give full control on web and lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved in this way:

1- adding in CustomAction Element:

```
 HostWebDialog="true"
 HostWebDialogHeight="300"
 HostWebDialogWidth="400"
```

2 in CommandUIHandlers a reference to a webpage:

```
 <CommandUIHandler
      Command="CustomTabExample.MyCommand"
        CommandAction="~appWebUrl/Pages/ClientWebPartTest2.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={SelectedItemId}&amp;SPListId={SelectedListId}" EnabledScript="javascript:SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems().length > 0;" />
```